# How to automatically chose a Time series Model for prediction?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting

I have a scenario where I have to forecast values for next one hour. My time series is in Hourly frequency. At first the data looks like it doesn't have trend or seasonality and it's stationary. So, I can apply simple ARMA model and make my forecasting. However, I can't use the same model for long time. After few days or months the data set might show some seasonality. In this case we have to again analyse the data manually and chose correct Time series model to fit. Simple ARMA model which we were already using won't give me expected forecasting results.

We can take example of CPU usage forecasting for an application. Initially usage might be stationary. After some time usage might show some trend/seasonality.

How should I handle this case? Is there a way where we can automatically decide which model to use and then train the data from that and make forecasting?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried auto-ARIMA? - https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forecast/versions/8.10/topics/auto.arima

Otherwise, Facebook Prophet might be an option.

Comment: Yes, I have tried. However, when you pass in the parameter to auto_arima you have to say whether it is seasonal or stationary. Like auto_arima(data, seasonal=True, m=somevalue). If I am automating, I don't know if it is seaonal or stationary

Comment: Hmm yeah. Got you. According to documentation, if seasonal parameter is not passed auto_arima searches through stationary and seasonal data.